# Is there a more elegant way of writing a function that returns the name of an image based on the argument of the function?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which has a property called `tier` which has 9 possible values - `IRON, BRONZE, SILVER, GOLD, PLATINUM, DIAMOND, MASTER, GRANDMASTER and CHALLENGER`.

Based on that property, I want to display the emblem corresponding to the tier, however, whilst the tier might be called `IRON`, the image file with the emblem would be called `Emblem_Iron`.

This is why I've created a function which takes a `tier` as an argument and then returns the file name of the emblem image corresponding to the `tier` so that I could do this:

```
<img class='ranked-emblem' :src="'../emblems/' + rankedEmblem(league.tier) + '.png'" alt="">
```

And my function is:

```
rankedEmblem(tier){
    if (tier === 'IRON') {
        return 'Emblem_Iron'
    } else if (tier === 'BRONZE') {
        return 'Emblem_Bronze'
    } else if (tier === 'SILVER') {
        return 'Emblem_Silver'
    } else if (tier === 'GOLD') {
        return 'Emblem_Gold'
    } else if (tier === 'PLATINUM') {
        return 'Emblem_Platinum'
    } else if (tier === 'DIAMOND') {
        return 'Emblem_Diamond'
    } else if (tier === 'MASTER') {
        return 'Emblem_Master'
    } else if (tier === 'GRANDMASTER') {
        return 'Emblem_Grandmaster'
    } else if (tier === 'CHALLENGER') {
        return 'Emblem_Challenger'
    }
}
```

While this works completely fine, I was wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing this that would shorten the function and maybe remove a couple of if els.

Comment: `switch/case` seems like the obvious choice.  Also, string interpolation after putting the `tier` into Pascalcase is another option.

Comment: hashmap object is an alternative. So is string parser

Comment: It looks like the output is straightforwardly buildable from the input.  Isn't it just capitalize and prepend Emblem_?

Comment: If `tier` is a number, an array of strings indexed by `tier` would work. If it's a string, an object or `Map` will do.

Comment: @kshetline `tier` is a string.  OP is comparing it against various strings.

Comment: On a dev note: stop mixing case in your filenames. Generating a 404 just because the casing was off is a headache you don't want to have to deal with, and don't need to deal with.

Comment: So many beautiful and clean answers. I've decided to pick the Nick Zoum's answer but the others were great as well. About the case in the file names, they're supplied by the creators of the API I'm using so those are their original names. In fairness I could rename them to IRON from Emblem_Iron and literally avoid having to use a function but that would only work because I have access to the files and can freely edit them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a plain `Object` as a map.

```js
var emblems = {
  IRON: "Emblem_Iron",
  BRONZE: "Emblem_Bronze",
  SILVER: "Emblem_Silver",
  GOLD: "Emblem_Gold",
  PLATINUM: "Emblem_Platinum",
  DIAMOND: "Emblem_Diamond",
  MASTER: "Emblem_Master",
  GRANDMASTER: "Emblem_Grandmaster",
  CHALLENGER: "Emblem_Challenger"
};

function rankedEmblem(tier) {
  // Could also help user by doing:  emblems[tier.toUpperCase()]
  return emblems[tier] || "No_Emblem";
}

console.log(rankedEmblem("GOLD"));
console.log(rankedEmblem("PLATINUM"));
```

Comment: Wow that looks clean! I think I'll use this.

Comment: I was so impressed how cleaner this is I forgot to thank you. Thanks for taking your time to help.

Comment: @Bobimaru I'm gload you liked this method. I personally despise switches and chained if elses. I use this pattern whenever I get the chance. One good use for it are messages (i.e. `{errShort: "Text is too short", errLong: "Text is too long" ...}`).

Answer (score 8):

You can use String concatination and functions like so:

```js
function rankedEmblem(tier){
    return "Emblem_" + tier.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + tier.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

console.log(rankedEmblem("CHALLENGER"));
```

Comment: but only if `tier` has been validate. Otherwise, this function will happily either a non-existent image, or even crash when `tier` is somehow undefined. Also remember that modern JS has template strings, which has made `+` for strings (which is unpredictable due to type coercion) no longer necessary.

Comment: Yep, on second thought I would also prefer using an object for mapping and returning a placeholder image for an unknown value.

Answer (score 6):

```
rankedEmblem(tier){
  let myEmblems = {IRON: 'Emblem_Iron', BRONZE: 'Emblem_Bronze' }; 
  //You can put whatever emblem you want as key:value pair
  return myEmblems[tier];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
rankedEmblem(tier) {
  return 'Emblem_' + tier.substr(0, 1) + tier.substr(2).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're in Javascript: use an object. There is no reason for `if` or `which` when you *know what the mapping is*:

```
// this mapping will probably live in its own file
const mapping = {
  IRON: `emblem-Iron.png`,
  GOLD: `emblem-Gold.png`,
  ...
}

// this function will probably _also_ live in its own file,
// and import that mapping (either with import or require).
function getImageForTier(tier) {
  let tierImage = mapping[tier];

  if (!tierImage) {
    // ... somehow, your code allowed for an unknown tier to make it this far.
    console.error(`unknown tier ${tier}!`);
    return UNKNOWN_TIER_IMAGE;
  }

  return tierImage;
}
```

You could use a function to just blindly generate the image filename based on the tier string, but then you run into the problem of "what about if the tier is actually wrong/unknown?".

If you already validate the tier somewhere earlier, then you don't even need a function, a template string will let you do this. But then at least make sure all your image filenames are in lowercase, because you should be able to rely on assets existing, and having to worry about "are there supposed to be capital letters in this file?" makes a dev life unnecessarily difficult:

```
image.src = `${baselocation}/ember-${tier.toLowerCase()}.png`
```